# public folder does not push to heroku repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

My public folder including my javascripts and css do not push to my heroku repository even though the rest of my code does.

I can't figure out why. Below is my `.gitignore` and my `gemfile . Any ideas??

```
.GITIGNORE

.bundle
db/*.sqlite3
log/*.log
tmp/**/*
db/schema.rb

GEMFILE:

source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'

gem "haml"

gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
gem 'nifty-generators'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :require => 'sqlite3'

gem 'devise', '1.1.rc0'

gem 'activemerchant', '1.9.3'
gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'

gem 'log4r', '1.1.9'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'chronic'
gem 'oauth2', '0.1.1'
gem 'shove'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'



# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'


group :development do
    gem 'ruby-debug19' 
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :test do
    gem 'ruby-debug19'
    gem 'rspec'
    gem 'webrat'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

Comment: did you git add the public dir?

Comment: What is the output of this command? `git ls-files public/javascripts --error-unmatch`

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting and recreating the public folder and check with `git status` if it detects it.  Looks like the folder is untracked.  Have you checked your `.gitignore_global` file if you've defined one?

If this fails, create another folder called `public2, add it, and commit it.  Then rename it back to public and see if git picks up on it.